# Player freezes after touching wall in maze game and won't move

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I'm trying to code so you can't walk thorugh the wall, so far the player does stop if you touch the wall, but won't move after touching it, it's completely stuck.

Can you see what the problem is with the code?

```
if(rightPressed)    
{
    if(playerMc.x<800)  
    {
        if(overworldMc.hitTestPoint(playerMc.x+15,playerMc.y,true)) 
        {
            playerMc.x += playerSpeed; playerSpeed= 0;
        } 
        else 
        {
            playerMc.y += playerSpeed; playerSpeed= 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because if you stop your player completely while the hit test is true, then it isn't moving anymore and forever stuck in the hit test.    If the hit test succeeds, you need to move the player back to it's last known position that wasn't touching the wall OR figure out the closest non touching point and move the player there.

Comment: dido to BadFeelingAboutThis. Beat me to it.

Comment: Also, please format your code nicely when posting.  It would have only taken you an extra few seconds to do so.